# Card "stack" and targeting in Unstable Unicorns- Irrelevance of a defensive Super Neigh

Tags: unstable-unicorns

In Unstable Unicorns, there are certain cards called "Neighs." A Neigh can be played at any time, and effectively "counters" a played card (similarly to Magic: The Gathering, or the "Nopes" in Exploding Kittens). There are also "Super Neighs-" Neigh cards that, additionally, cannot be Neighed. It seems to me that Super Neighs don't actually have any effect on gameplay other than normal Neighs when played defensively. It seems to me that the most logical way to resolve Neighs is similar to the "stack" in Magic. This would indicate that if, for example, your opponent plays a Pandamonium, and you choose to Neigh it, if they then play a Super Neigh in an attempt to win the "Neigh War" that may ensue, you could simply choose to play another Neigh, targeting the Pandamonium again, rather than the Super Neigh. Is this correct? Is there any reason that I MUST target the most recently played card with a Neigh, if there are multiple cards still unresolved?

**TL;DR: Does Unstable Unicorns utilize a similar "stack" system to Magic, leaving cards unresolved and still Neighable until all more recently played cards have resolved?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://unstablegameswiki.com/index.php?title=Neigh,_Neigh%27d,_Neighable,_Neighing

In Unstable Unicorns the stack is literally a stack.  The card being played is placed on top of the card it is responding to.  Therefore the only card targetable is the one on top of the stack.

The Super Neigh is the end of the stack and the entire stack will then resolve.